# Where is the defination of rails validators?

Tags: oop, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner in rails. As I was working on rails validation, I wanted to know where is the definition of `valid?` and `new_record?` and all the validation helpers?

I was trying to find the definition of all these functions but couldn't find any.

Where do all this validations reside? As I know Ruby on Rails is pure object oriented programming language.

Any help will be appreciated. I already went through
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is the link to the current UniquenessValidator class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d73d6e7b6dd1900f105397460b777ef6c03d3b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb

Comment: Thank you very much but I was looking for the definition in my own system not on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Rails methods:

You can find `valid?` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) and its code on [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/59190c037999d302dd95b1f53f7049c2cec3f7b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L56).

Likewise with `new_record?`, you can find a description and its source code [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F).

Also, here is a link to the Rails repository on [Github.](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/59190c037999d302dd95b1f53f7049c2cec3f7b9)

These methods are not defined in the project, they are defined in the rails gem which you have in your Gemfile.

Comment: i actually wanted to know where they are defined in project?

Comment: They are not defined in the project, they are defined in the rails gem which you have in your Gemfile and which I have linked to above.